# Facebook API Error Code: 191

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-canvas

I would really appreciate some help. I've searched around, and I feel like I've tried everything but to no avail.

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
```

These are my settings:

```
App Domains: localhost
Canvas URL: http://localhost/friendsmash/
Secure Canvas URL: *empty*
App Available to Public: No
Valid OAuth redirect URIs: http://localhost/friendsmash/
```

Edit:

I get the error when I try to go to the canvas URL. In other words, I put:

```
http://localhost/friendsmash/
```

in my browser. It redirects me here: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=592670390826338&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Ftestappertest%2F&state=8712a908d02c6b6fc3fa9c19c9747296&scope=email%2Cpublish_actions

Then, I see the error. When I go to the canvas page instead, I get a blank page. As for the code, I am following this tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas/canvas-tutorial

I censored the app id and secret. Anyway, this is the relevant part of the code:

```
<?php
require 'server/fb-php-sdk/facebook.php';

$app_id = 'XXXXXX';
$app_secret = 'XXXXXX';
$app_namespace = 'testappertest';
$app_url = 'https://apps.facebook.com/' . $app_namespace . '/';
$scope = 'email,publish_actions';

// Init the Facebook SDK
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
));

// Get the current user
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// If the user has not installed the app, redirect them to the Login Dialog
if (!$user) {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope' => $scope,
        'redirect_uri' => $app_url,
    ));
    print('<script> top.location.href=\'' . $loginUrl . '\'</script>');
}
?>
```

Comment: When do you see this error message? Please post some code.

Comment: I have added some more info on this with some code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: If you want to use login with Facebook from outside of Facebook (and that is what you are doing when you are calling your page via `http://localhost/friendsmash/` directly), then you have to add the “website” platform in your app settings. And inside facebook.com (canvas/page tab), I’d recommend using FB.login out of the JS SDK for login instead, it makes for a much nicer user experience (login dialog overlayed over the page, instead of a redirect).